# iTextSharp PDF Footer not visible in Adobe Reader

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, footer

I am adding footer text to existing BYTES in each page using the code shown below, which is visible in Chrome as well as in Foxit PhantomPDF, however, it's not visible in Adobe PDF reader.

In addition to the footer, I also add headers which are visible even with Adobe.

```
private byte[] AddPageHeaderFooter(byte[] pdf, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop,
    float marginBottom, DataSet prospectDetails, ref int startingPageNumber, string logoPath, bool isLandscape = false)
{
    var dataRow = prospectDetails.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    var prospectDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow[0]);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
        var reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1), marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop,
            marginBottom);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        var pageIndex = startingPageNumber;
        for (var page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            pageIndex++;
            var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page);
            if (isLandscape)
                contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,
                    reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page).Height);
            else
                contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
            contentByte.BeginText();
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            // Code to add header 

            // Footer
            // Not visible parts **START**
            contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 7);
            var prospectDateString = string.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", prospectDate);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER,
                "FOOTER LINE 1",
                isLandscape ? 398 : 305f, 50, 0);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER,
                "FOOTER LINE 2", isLandscape ? 398 : 305f, 42, 0);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,
                prospectDateString.Substring(5, prospectDateString.Length - 5), document.Left, marginBottom, 0);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "-     " + pageIndex + "     -",
                isLandscape ? 398 : 305f, marginBottom, 0);
            contentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, string.Format("{0:T}", prospectDate),
                document.Right, marginBottom, 0);
            contentByte.EndText();
            contentByte.SaveState();
            // Not visible parts **END**

            // Footer line
            // Not visible parts **START**
            contentByte.SetColorStroke(new PdfSpotColor("black", new BaseColor(0, 0, 0)), 100);
            contentByte.SetLineWidth(0.25f);
            contentByte.Rectangle(marginLeft, 58, isLandscape ? 732 : 552, 0.25f);
            contentByte.FillStroke();
            // Not visible parts **END**

            contentByte.RestoreState();
        }
        startingPageNumber = pageIndex;
        document.Close();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

1. Only the footer line that I draw is visible in Adobe.
2. Footer texts namely, footer line 1, footer line 2, Date as well as page number is not visible even when I try to print the document.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Please share a sample result PDF for analysis.

Comment: I actually asked for a sample result **PDF** for analysis. You can see the text in some viewers and not in others, so the obvious path to go is to inspect the PDF internals. That obviously does not work with screenshots...

Comment: @mkl I don't have permission to share that document that's the problem

Comment: @mkl any link you can share where I can read and do the internals checking you mentioned?

Comment: Try to find a neutral PDF (one which you can share) which shows the same behavior after being processed by your code above. I would inspect the internal structures and command streams looking for some clue what goes wrong; for this I would use a tool like iText RUPS or PDFBox Debugger and have the PDF specification open in another window.

Comment: As an aside: If you only want to add headers and footers, why do you not use the iText `PdfStamper`? It is usually the class of choice for such manipulations.

Comment: @mkl will try to implement PdfStamper if the footer issue is not resolved. Thank you